# How to define something in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know how to define something in C++. For example:

```
#define ce cout<<"\n";
```

now if we use `ce` any where of the code it will output `cout<<"\n";`
I am trying with this JavaSvript:

```
#define go document.write
```

So, if i want to show/output something, i wish to write

```
go('Great!');
```

now, this will output `Great!` in the browser. But this `define` method not working in JavaScript

Comment: JavaScript and C++ are not the same programming language

Comment: `malloc` doesn't in JavaScript either, damn!

Comment: @hunter: what's more, if you try and program JavaScript like C++, you're going to have a horrible time!

Comment: well, i just want to minimize the code, I KNOW ABOUT **VaRiAbLe**

Comment: you can still minimize the code, but you'll need to learn the ways to do that in javascript. perhaps start with anonymous functions, closures, and partial evaluation/currying. also remember that (almost) everything in javascript is an object, so you can do things like assigning functions to variables.

Comment: after c++ (converting my c++ lib in js ) javascript was such a pain...but gradually i started liking this reckless language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't, at least not the way C/C++ does it. You can however assign a function to any variable:

```
var go = document.write;
```

As pointed out this won't work for `document.write` because of the scope change. One solution to get an actual function with the correct scope would be:

```
var go = document.write.bind(document);
// Now call
go('Great!');
```

Node that `.bind` won't work in IE8 and lower.

Comment: Note that this will not work in a lot of cases, as the value of `this` changes once you reference the function directly, rather than through `document`. For instance, `var l = console.log; l('foo');` fails in Chrome. To get around this you can use `Function.prototype.bind` in ES5 land (`var l = console.log.bind(console);`, or you'll have to use an anonymous wrapper.

Comment: i think this will not output `Great!`

Comment: True indeed. I should have tried it. Fixed :)

Comment: `document.write.bind(document);` is good 1 !

Comment: yeah, it is. but please make sure you understand how it works!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is with `Object.defineProperty`, which allows you to set something that isn't writable, configurable, or enumerable...specifically on the `window` object (so there is global access). Try this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "go", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xm3mT/

Instead of setting the `value` as an anonymous function, you can use `bind`, like:

```
value: console.log.bind(console)
```

Although it would be just as fine to use my first example.

I'm not exactly sure of your use of `document.write`, but you normally don't want to use that...of course, it's up to you. Nonetheless, I used `console.log` instead just for an example.

References:

- `Object.defineProperty` docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty
- `Object.defineProperty` browser compatibility - http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.defineProperty
- `Function.prototype.bind` docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
- `Function.prototype.bind` browser compatibility - http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind

Comment: It is important to note that `Object.defineProperty` isn't supported properly on IE<9.

Comment: @Matt That's why I included the compatibility of it as a reference :)

Comment: Aha, it didn't stand out that much amongst all the references ;) (not complaining, wish all answers on Stack Overflow were this detailed ;)).

Comment: @Matt I know you weren't :) But you're right - sometimes I forget to add a minor description before the reference...I just updated. And thank you for saying that :)

Answer (score 1):

You define a variable using the "var" keyword.

`var name = "Jessica";`

You can assign a function as well:
`var myFunction = function() {

  // do something

};`

Javascript is loose typed, so you don't specify what type of variable it is.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is not a compiled language, so there's no equivalent to C++'s `define`. You'll have to use variables. But you can assign functions to variables (as functions in JavaScript are objects) to get essentially the same result.