# What is the Javascript equivalent to C++'s #define?

Tags: javascript, c++

For-each loops in JS are "dangerous" to use on arrays, and I can't simply do

```
for (var idx in arr)
```

and instead have to do

```
for (var idx = 0, len = arr.length; idx < len; ++idx)
```

which is very laborious to type. Suppose it takes 3 seconds to type and I have to type it 10,000 times in my life ...

**3s x 10,000 / 60h = 500h**

**500h * $28/h = $14,000**

It would be better to have a compact way of creating this common line of code. It would be nice to have some preprocessor directive like

```
#define L(arr,idx,len) for (var idx = 0, len = arr.length; idx < len; ++idx)
```

and then I could just write stuff like

```
var myArray = [1, 69, 193912];
L(myArray,k,n)
{
   // ... 
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What about http://www.nongnu.org/espresso/js-cpp.html

Comment: `arr.forEach(function(el, i)  { ... })`

Comment: As a matter of fact, you can. Just do that and give it to a c preprocessor.

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426295/how-to-define-something-in-javascript

Comment: No no no, please don't do such things. While you might safe some seconds every time you type this, everyone else working with your code will have to use much more type to find out what the hell you did there. That's *terrible* style. (Speaking from a C++ point of view, but I would guess that this is just as bad in Java.)

Comment: I disagree that [iterating an array using a for...in loop is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea). It's only dangerous if you either don't know how it works, or happen to be using a library / framework which extends the array prototype, which is just stupid and I would much rather find that out sooner than later.

Comment: ES6 arrow functions even make it more compact: `arr.forEach((el, i)=>{...})`

Comment: A majority of software cost is maintenance which relates to the ability of others to easily read, understand, and modify/maintain the code. Saving a few seconds of typing in an obfuscated way **_will cost a lot more in the long run_**.

Comment: Very good point! Those calculations must be of one of the reasons behind getting fired from "GOOG and MS" :)

Comment: Use kripken/emscripten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Javascript does not have a preprocessor like C/C++ so there is no direct equivalent to C's #define in Javascript.**

The only pseudo replacement that is built into the language is to use an actual function rather than a preprocessor expansion which is executed at runtime, not at parse/compile time.

So, your options are:

1. Use the regular **`for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`** loop that everyone knows and understands.
2. Use **`.forEach()`**, the built-in array iterator
3. Create **your own function** that will do the iteration (no real point when `.forEach()` is already there).
4. Use the [ES6 `of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) as in **`for (let i of arr)`**.  You can either use this directly in an ES6 supported environment or you can use a transpiler like Babel.
5. Use a **preprocessing step** in your build system so you can actually add preprocessing to your JS files and have something like #define.

A safe recommendation would be to use `.forEach()` and add a polyfill if versions of IE before IE9 are required or go with the ES6/transpiler option (which has many other benefits too).

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ are compiled languages and the `#define` you are referring to is a pre processor macro, which are used by the preprocessor to aid in compiling for platform specific compilation.

As far as I know there are no libraries that solve your problem in JavaScript, but you can check npmjs.org because I may be wrong.

Nevertheless, I have three ideas for you:

1. Writing your own preprocessor to your liking and then just using it as part of your build normal js build routine. Then upload it to npm and become famous
2. Use the Gcc preprocessor without the compiler: `gcc-E path/to/file`and directing its output to a file, which can also be part of your js build routine. A ridiculous example:

   ```
   #define FOR(s,end) for(i=s;i<=end;i++)
   #define P console.log
   #define func function



   func add(a,x){

       P(a+x)

   }

   FOR(1,10){

       add(i,i)
   }
   ```
3. Write your own functions to make life easier. Instead using loop syntax, write functions like `loop( start, finish, callback)`. But even this is the same amount of writing. I would look at options 1 and 2.

But like many of the comments, doing this is Js can cause confusion and waste much more time for others reading your code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

in C:

```
   #define max(a,b) (a>b ? a : b)
   to use it:
   int result = max(2,3);
```

in JS:

```
   let max = (a,b) => a>b ? a : b; 
   so use it:
   let result = max(2,3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really the same, but you can define your own function like that one:

```
function myFor(arr, fn) {
    for(var i = 0; I < arr.length; i++) {
        fn(i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Thus you can use it as it follows:

```
myFor(myArr, myForEachFn);
```

Where the second argument is a function you want to apply on each element.
Besides the long names I've used, it's faster to type than the `for` loop above.

Comment: Javascript has a built-in function `forEach()` that does the same thing. Why define your own?

Comment: For he asked an equivalent to `#define` and I gave him an example.

Comment: @Barmar I mean, which was the question? An efficient way to do a `forEach` or how to type less using something like a define? To me, it looked like the second one, likely not the same to you... :-)